# Facebook login on iOS FBSDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, ios9, fbsdk

I setup everything same as FB developer page (appId, appName, bundleId...). I work on FBSDK 4.6 and iOS 9. I also already added this key on info.plist.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

However, when running, I received the output error like this:

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"
```

Anyone know what happened?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 9 you have add more keys to the info.plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>facebook.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>        
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>fbcdn.net</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>  <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>akamaihd.net</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

[Facebook getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)

Comment: I've already added it. If not, you will get an exception as the document from fb developer page describe.

Answer (score 0):

Run the app on your phone to test with Facebook installed. It might be because it doesn't work on the simulator or facebook has to be installed.

Comment: Ah, I can run on device, but my current device on iOS 8.
I changed behavior on FBSDKLoginManager to Browser or Web or SystemAccount, but no any lucky on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

i would ignore it.

per their FAQs, facebook acknowledges this and recommends you let it go so as long as you've properly set up their plist settings

> **Why do I see console messages like 'canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb...://' or ?**
>
> This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist as described above, you can **ignore** this warning

source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9